# Swift 2 - how to get data from Alamofire.responseJSON

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm reading Design+Code course and Ihave 2 files:

1. DNService.swift
2. StoriesTableViewController.swift

Form the DNService I'm loading data from DesignerNews API, here is the function who get the data :

```
static func storiesForSection(section: String, page: Int, response: (JSON) ->()) {

    let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.Stories.description + "/" + section
    let parameters = [
        "page": String(page),
        "client_id": clientID
    ]



    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        let swiftyData = JSON(response.result.value ?? [])
        //print(swiftyData)
    }


}
```

In the `StoriesTableViewController`, I call the function `storiesForSection()` but it don't retrieve the data :

```
var stories: JSON! = []

func loadStories(section: String, page: Int) {
    DNService.storiesForSection(section, page: page) { (JSON) -> () in
        self.stories = JSON["stories"]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fill `self.stories` in my `StoriesTableViewcontroller`...

I tried to store swiftyData in a var of DNService and make a `getStoredSwiftyData()` in `StoriesTableViewCtler` but it doesn't works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storiesForSection:page:response` has a callback function, just call it with the JSON object as parameter.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
    let swiftyData = JSON(response.result.value ?? [])
    response(swiftyData)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer, I tried but I have this error : "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Response<AnyObject, NSError>"

Comment: I already suspected there is a terminology clash with the two `response` objects. Can you change that one in `storiesForSection` to a different name? Or assign the first `response` object to a local variable with a different name.

Comment: Thank you, it was this ! loadStories() was inside another function with another callback called "responses"

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Swift4
   import Alamofire
```

//only Getting Data from .get methods After getting data you can convert it into your suitable formate

```
   let url2:URL=URL(string: values)!
    Alamofire.request(url2).response 
     { response in
        if(response.data != nil)
          {

           }
          else{
            print(response.error)

               }
 }
```